How to add custom claims in id_token node oidc provider
I am using node oidc provider (https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider) with nodejs/express.
I am trying to add custom claims in the jwt id_token as part of the authorization flow.
In the oidcConfiguration object i have added the following claims:
claims: {
  openid: ['sub'],
  twoFa: ['twoFaEnabled', 'twoFaSuccess'],
},

My login interaction handler looks like this:
login: async (req, res) => {
  const { prompt: { name }, uid, params } = await oidc.interactionDetails(req, res)

  if (name === "login") {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    const decodedState = Buffer.from(params.state, 'base64').toString('utf-8')
    const state = JSON.parse(decodedState)

    await withConnection(async connection => {
      const user = await connection.querySingle('SELECT id, passwd FROM user WHERE email=?', [email])

      if (!user) {
        let errorKey = "access_denied"
        let errorDescription = "Username or password is incorrect"

        return res.redirect(`/interaction/${uid}?error-key=${errorKey}&error-description=${errorDescription}&email=${encodeURIComponent(email)}`)
      } else {
        const passwordMatches = await samePassword(password, user.passwd)
        if (!passwordMatches) {
          let errorKey = "access_denied"
          let errorDescription = "Username or password is incorrect"

          return res.redirect(`/interaction/${uid}?error-key=${errorKey}&error-description=${errorDescription}&email=${encodeURIComponent(email)}`)
        } else {
          let result = {
            login: {
              accountId: user.id.toString(),
            },
            meta: {
              twoFa: {
                twoFaEnabled: true,
                twoFaSuccess: false,
              },
            },
          }

          // Finalize the interaction with the result
          return oidc.interactionFinished(req, res, result, {
            mergeWithLastSubmission: false,
          })
        }
      }
    })
  }
},

And in the confirmInteraction handler, this is the code:
confirmInteraction: async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Get interaction details
    const interactionDetails = await oidc.interactionDetails(req, res)
    const {
      prompt: { name, details },
      params,
      session: { accountId },
      lastSubmission,
    } = interactionDetails

    // Check if prompt name is 'consent'
    if (name === 'consent') {
      // Retrieve or create a new grant
      const grant = interactionDetails.grantId
        ? await oidc.Grant.find(interactionDetails.grantId)
        : new oidc.Grant({
            accountId,
            clientId: params.client_id,
          })

      if (grant) {
        // Add missing OIDC scopes, claims, and resource scopes to the grant
        if (details.missingOIDCScope) {
          grant.addOIDCScope(details.missingOIDCScope.join(' '))
        }
        if (details.missingOIDCClaims) {
          grant.addOIDCClaims(details.missingOIDCClaims)
        }
        if (details.missingResourceScopes) {
          for (const [indicator, scopes] of Object.entries(details.missingResourceScopes)) {
            grant.addResourceScope(indicator, scopes.join(' '))
          }
        }

        // Save the grant and finish the interaction
        const grantId = await grant.save()
        const result = { consent: { grantId } }

        await oidc.interactionFinished(req, res, result, {
          mergeWithLastSubmission: true,
        })
      }
    } else {
      // Respond with an error if the prompt type is not 'consent'
      res.status(400).send('Interaction prompt type must be `consent`.')
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors
    console.error('Error in confirmInteraction:', error)
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')
  }
},

Printing the grant after adding all the missing claims etc returns me this:
Grant {
  accountId: '3',
  clientId: 'oidc_client',
  kind: 'Grant',
  jti: undefined,
  openid: { scope: 'openid twoFa' }
}

At this point when the id_token is requested I get this response:
{
  sub: '3',
  at_hash: 'iZmspVwr89I4xloppwJWwA',
  aud: 'oidc_client',
  exp: 1732012978,
  iat: 1732009378,
  iss: 'http://localhost:3050'
}

So I need in this object the "twoFaEnabled" and "twoFaSuccess" properties as well. How do I add them there?
Thanks for the help!
